# SQL Query to analyze Test Data

Tags: sql-server

We have a number of tables in SQL with test result data.

Example Table:

```
Timestamp   SN          FreqMin   CarrierFreq  FreqMax

2015-06-01  00123445    1000      1500         2000
2015-06-01  100000000   1000      0            2000
2015-06-01  00123446    1000      1500         2000
2015-06-01  100123445   1000      2500         2000
```

We would like to query the tables to analyze the test results.

I am getting 'Incorrect Syntax near 'AS'' in the following query.

```
SELECT  Count(*) AS 'Total Records',
    CASE 
        WHEN LEN(SN) = '8' THEN (SUM(CASE WHEN LEN(SN) = '8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Pass'
        WHEN SN = '100000000' THEN SUM(1) AS 'IR Failure'
        WHEN SN != '100000000' AND LEN(SN) = '9' THEN
            SUM(CASE WHEN LEN(SN) = '9' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fail',
            SUM(CASE WHEN CarrierFreq NOT BETWEEN FreqMin AND FreqMax THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Carrier Freq Fail'
        !Add in a lot more tests similar to the line above
    END 

  FROM [SERVER].[dbo].[Table]

 WHERE TestDate >= '2015-06-01'
```

What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

If LEN(SN) = '8', then increment Pass column value and do not do any more analysis on that row.
IF SN = '100000000', then it is an IR failure, increment IR Failure column and do not do any more analysis on that row.
IF SN != '100000000' AND LEN(SN) = '9', then check for failures and tally each one.

If I just have my query doing the
        `SUM(CASE WHEN CarrierFreq NOT BETWEEN FreqMin AND FreqMax THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`     AS 'Carrier Freq Fail'
statements, I can return all the data properly.  But there are false failures in the tally, since any tests with IR Failures will have default data that will not pass.

So from the Table above, the results would be:

```
Total Records = 4
Pass = 2
IR Failure = 1
Fail = 1
Carrier Freq Fail = 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! A few things you can do to improve this question: add some sample data and expected results, and verify if you are using MySQL or SQL-Server and remove the unnecessary tag.

Comment: @McAdam331 You can tell it's SQL Server by the use of `[dbo]`. Having some sample data and the expected results would be nice though.

Comment: @Mureinik thanks for clearing that up, I must have skimmed over it.

Comment: I have added a data table and the requested Results.

Comment: The syntax of your `CASE` statements is wrong; the `AS` keyword makes no sense inside the `CASE`. They should read `CASE WHEN <condition 1> THEN <expression 1> ... WHEN <condition n> THEN <expression n> ELSE <default expression> END AS <alias>`. edit - To add to this, if you want to get more than one column, you need more than one `CASE` statement. If they are all on the same conditions, consider extracting the common logic into a CTE that encapsulates those conditions, and gives an integer value to each case, then you can switch on that value repeatedly for better readability.

Comment: You need to do a separate CASE Statement for each derived column in your desired output.